# Perl 5.12 loading Module with DLL created for Perl 5.6

Tags: windows, perl, dll, binary, perl-module

I am supposed to switch our development environment from ActiveState Perl 5.6.0 to Strawberry Perl 5.12 but I am stuck on one Module.

We have created our own Module which also includes a dll (for performance reasons).  Now that module was compiled for Perl 5.6.0.  The Problem is, that we do not have the sourcecode anymore, but we need to get that module somehow working with the new Perl Version.

Is there even any chance to do this, without having to recompile that module for perl 5.12?

When I try to load it, it says that it cant find the required dll, but the path is correct and the file is there, so it seems to be a loading problem with the versions.

TIA
Patrick

Comment: Need more information. How is the DLL being used by this Perl module? Are there any Perl modules being utilized to use the DLL? Please provide the exact error message.

Comment: @Zaid, He's talking about compiled XS code ("compiled module").

Comment: You're going to have to compile it for a new version of Perl. Which means you are going to have to rewrite it. There really isn't any good way around it.

Answer (score 4):

No. The Perl library is not guarantee to maintain binary compatibility between major versions, and something compiled for 5.6 is not binary compatible with the Perl 5.12 library. The only way to load that module is if Perl 5.6 is involved somehow.

Comment: Yea I figured as much.  I actually just found a Perl only Version of this module, which has some performance problems (thats why the .dll extended perl module was generated in first place).  It works but performance is slugish in cgi, should get better when we switch to fcgi I hope.